# Getting other PC microphone audio input using python

Tags: python, microphone, pyaudio

I would like to know how to save other PC microphone audio input into my PC using python.I use below code but it is not work for getting other PC microphone input.Please help to advise.

```
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 8000
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 2
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tester_0_0.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE, input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print("recording...")
frames = []
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print("finished recording")

# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
waveFile.close()
```

Comment: can you run a python program on the other pc's mic?

Comment: This program is running in my local server. Client's microphone input cannot be taken  by server.